# Compile DocxFactory based application with gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, docx

I am trying to compile a minimal example from [DocxFactory](http://docxfactory.com/free-download/). The example is taken from [C++ Tutorial](http://docxfactory.com/download/128/).

The following steps where performed:

- Download [DocxFactory library for 64-bit Linux](http://docxfactory.com/download/136/)
- Extract and install the library as described in [C++ Tutorial](http://docxfactory.com/download/128/)
- After that, an example file was created (top_level.cpp)

top_level.cpp:

```
#include "WordProcessingCompiler.h"
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace DocxFactory;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    try
    {
        WordProcessingCompiler& l_compiler =
            WordProcessingCompiler::getInstance();
        time_t l_start = clock();
        l_compiler.compile(
            "/opt/DocxFactory/exercises/templates/top_level_items.docx",
            "/opt/DocxFactory/exercises/templates/top_level_items.dfw");
        cout<< "Completed (in "
            << (double) (clock() - l_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
            << " seconds)."
            << endl;
    }
    catch (const exception& p_exception)
    {
        cout << p_exception.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

After that it will be compiled, as written in the tutorial, with:

```
g++ -c top_level.cpp /opt/DocxFactory/src/WordProcessingCompiler.cpp /opt/DocxFactory/src/WordProcessingMerger.cpp -I/opt/DocxFactory/include
```

Finally the linking failed with

```
g++ -o top_level top_level.o WordProcessingCompiler.o WordProcessingMerger.o -L/opt/DocxFactory/lib -lDocxFactory
//opt/DocxFactory/lib/libDocxFactoryLib.so: undefined reference to `ZBarcode_Export'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Since this is a linking error, it's clear that one or more additional dynamic libraries are missing.

**Questions**

- Did anybody else running into the same problem and solved it already?
- What library contains a function or a class with the name ZBarcode_Export?

Answer (score 1):

DocxFactory uses [Zint](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/) to generate barcodes. libzint.so is the Zint shared library.

Have you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or used ldconfig?

Kind regards,
Alon